# How to tell if the current operating system is OpenBSD in NeoVim?

Tags: neovim, openbsd

I use NeoVim on two machines, one running OpenBSD and another running Linux. I want to be able to run/load certain commands if I'm on the OpenBSD machine. How can I do this? I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```lua
if vim.fn.has('openbsd') then
  ... do stuff ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Neovim, you can use Vim functions to get OS name :

```
vim.loop.os_uname().sysname
```

- On Linux, function returns `Linux`
- On OpenBSD, function returns `OpenBSD`